# Are graded readers with monolingual glossaries commonly available?

Tags: english, graded-readers

I’ve been using the book “Read and Think Spanish” to improve my Spanish, and it’s been a great resource, because it provides information about vocabulary or short phrases, but otherwise is just an enjoyable collection of one or two page passages with interesting and informative content. As far as I know, it is a “graded reader”, because it’s for learning a foreign language.

Recently, I was trying to find a graded reader which is like that, but for learning English, with a monolingual glossary, and which has content about Australian culture. I tried asking at Abbey’s Language Book Centre, and the staff claimed that monolingual glossaries for graded readers are fairly uncommon. So far I haven’t tried looking for graded readers with a bilingual glossary which defines English words using Spanish definitions (such as [Read and Think English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071499164)), because most native speakers of Spanish who emigrate to an English-speaking country emigrate to the USA, so I anticipate most bilingual graded readers to be predominantly US-focused. Also, I assume that after a certain level of proficiency, it’s beneficial to use monolingual resources rather than bilingual ones.

The closest I got to what I wanted was [People in Australia's past : their stories, their achievements](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/38347588?q&versionId=214282148) which meets the requirement for one-page articles, and kind of gives a glossary, but it’s aimed at children.

Are graded readers with a monolingual glossary commonly available, and if not, is it because expert opinion exists that monolingual glossaries are unsuitable for language learning?

Comment: A monolingual book could not exist at the lower levels because the glossary would be incomprehensible.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Not necessarily, you could use pictures for many basic concepts, after all.

Comment: “Short Stories in English” by Oily Richards also has a monolingual glossary.